# Changing tags based on file name

Tags: id3, metadata

I am looking for software which changes the artist and song tags of a music file based on the file name. The filenames are all using the following pattern: `{{artist}} - {{song}}.{mp3|wav}`. It must also clear the other tags. It must run on Debian or Windows and I prefer a commandline program.

Comment: There are many of those. What OS must your choice run on? Do you prefer a GUI, or must it run from command-line? Any other specifics you require? Btw: I'm not aware that `.wav` files can hold "tags".

Comment: @Izzy Windows or Debian. Commandline. No, I have no other requirements. Yes, wav can hold tags.

Comment: I could recommend you a GUI program for Linux I use for MP3 tagging. It doesn't support tagging WAV files, though. Would you be interested in that?

Comment: @Izzy Yes, I'm interested in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using **[EasyTag](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/EasyTAG)** on Linux to tag my MP3 files. It's available via the repos of most Linux distributions, and supports MP3, MP2 files (ID3 tag with pictures), FLAC files (FLAC Vorbis tag), Ogg Opus files (Ogg Vorbis tag), Ogg Speex (Ogg Vorbis tag), Ogg Vorbis files (Ogg Vorbis tag), MP4/AAC (MP4/AAC tag), MusePack, Monkey's Audio files and WavPack files (APE tag).

[image: EasyTag] [image: EasyTag]
<sup>*EasyTag* main window and file name tag mask (source: [UbuntuWiki](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/EasyTAG/); click images for larger variants)</sup>

As you can see in the screenshots, *EasyTag* can derive tags from file names using "masks", with the most used masks already pre-defined (if your files use a different order, you can define your own mask). It works on entire directory trees – but it's completely up to you where files should be updated. If some information cannot be extracted from the file names, you can add/edit the corresponding fields manually. It's even possible to mass-edit a single (or multiple) field(s) for multiple files, e.g. if you wish to apply the same genre to them, by marking the required files before editing the field. Changes are not applied immediately, but only when you click the corresponding button.

According to its [project page](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/EasyTAG), *EasyTag* is available for Windows as well.